# Aws Lambda that calls other lambda with the same parameters?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a lambda function that needs to call another lambda and pass the same input parameters (event dictionary) However, my invocation fails. My invocation for 1st lambda is an s3 event

```
lambda_s3.invoke(
FunctionName='Function',
InvocationType='Event',
Payload=json.dumps(event)
)
```

I assume that Payload doesn't really work. How can I encode the payload so it's readable by the other lambda

json of the event that I try to pass:

```
        {  
    'Records':[  
        {  
            'eventVersion':'2.0',
            'eventSource':'aws:s3',
            'awsRegion':'us-east-1',
            'eventTime':'1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
            'eventName':'ObjectCreated:Put',
            'userIdentity':{  
                'principalId':'AIDAJDPLRKLG7UEXAMPLE'
            },
            'requestParameters':{  
                'sourceIPAddress':'127.0.0.1'
            },
            'responseElements':{  
                'x-amz-request-id':'C3D13FE58DE4C810',
                'x-amz-id-2':'FMyUVURIY8/IgAtTv8xRjskZQpcIZ9KG4V5Wp6S7S/JRWeUWerMUE5JgHvANOjpD'
            },
            's3':{  
                's3SchemaVersion':'1.0',
                'configurationId':'testConfigRule',
                'bucket':{  
                'name':'my-faces-data',
                'ownerIdentity':{  
                    'principalId':'A3NL1KOZZKExample'
                },
                'arn':'arn:aws:s3:::my-faces-data'
                },
                'object':{  
                'key':'images/banana.jpg',
                'size':1024,
                'eTag':'d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e',
                'versionId':'096fKKXTRTtl3on89fVO.nfljtsv6qko'
                }
            }
        }
    ]}
```

Comment: Can you print the `event` object to be sure it’s a json valid string.

Comment: what error do you receive?

Comment: My event is default s3 put event.  I receive it as an input to my first lambda and want to pass to the second as described in 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode the payload. Your invocation should look like this:

```
lambda_s3.invoke(
    FunctionName='Function',
    InvocationType='RequestResponse',
    Payload=json.dumps(event).encode()
)
```

Python boto3 explanation can be found [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/docs/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke).

Comment: That gives me an error ` "errorMessage": "<botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x7fe02e53dbe0> is not JSON serializable", `

Comment: Your event may not be a valid JSON.

Comment: it's the same event that I receive as an input to my first Lambda! Not sure why I can't pass it to the second function

Comment: Got it. You need to convert the input into a JSON. So, update the payload line to look like this: `Payload=json.dumps(json.loads(event)).encode()`. If it works, I will update the answer.

Comment: Silly question @KrishnaKumarR: why not just `Payload=event`?

Comment: Yeah, I'm also surprised why Payload = event doesn't work. I never change the event anyway but it gives `  type: <class 'dict'>, valid types: <class 'bytes'>, <class 'bytearray'>, file-like object", `

Comment: @Michael - what you suggested should work too. @Wideem, did it work? You need to encode the string. If `event` is a string, `Payload=event.encode()` should work. Else, to be safe, just implement: `Payload=str(event).encode()`.

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked.

```
client = boto3.client('lambda')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    payload = {'query':"SELECT c.name FROM vp.m_crops c WHERE c.id = 1"}
    payload = json.dumps(payload)

    resp = client.invoke(
        FunctionName='xxxxx',
        InvocationType='RequestResponse',
        LogType='Tail',
        Payload=payload,
        Qualifier='dev'
    )

    # gets the list of response from mysql
    resp = json.loads(resp['Payload'].read())

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': resp
    }
```

The error was not caused by the payload but caused by the lambda that invoked another lambda. JSON serialization failed at return.